# Class 'App/Post' not found in laravel-5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

While i was working on my laravel project i got this error and i am unable to solve it even after so much changes and effort. I hope i get some solution.

**My ERROR:**

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with
> message "Class 'App/Post' not found"

**CommentsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \Auth;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Comment;
use Session;
use DB;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{

public function store(Request $request)
{
     $this->validate($request, [
         'name' => 'required',
         'email' => 'required',
        'comment' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    $post = Post::find('id');

    $comments = new Comment();
    $comments->name = $request->name;
    $comments->email = $request->email;
    $comments->comment = $request->comment;
    $comments->approved = true;
    $comments->post()->associate($post);

    $comments->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'Comment was added');
    
     return redirect()->route('posts.show', [$post->id]);
    //return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Comment Created 
  Successfully');
   
}
}`
```

**Post.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
//Table Name
protected $table = 'posts';
//Primary Key
public $primaryKey = 'id';
//Timestamps
public $timestamps = true;

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function comment(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
}
```

**Web.php (Route File)**

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@contact');
Route::get('/services', 'PagesController@services');

// Post Pages
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');

// Login Authorization
Auth::routes();

// Dashboard
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');

// Comments
Route::post('/posts/{post_id}', ['uses'=>'CommentsController@store' , 'as' => 'comments.store']);
```

Comment: Where is the `Post.php` file located?

Comment: File is located in app/Post.php, the initial directory @Jerodev

Comment: Save file with name Post.php instaed of My post.php

Comment: Just use `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Not working even after using this command @berkaykılıç

Comment: Its already "Post.php" @SachinAghera

Comment: But you here show that file name is My post.php and name of class is post

Comment: that was misunderstanding, I edit my post @SachinAghera

Comment: aside note: in your url  `'/posts/{post_id}'` you have a parameter, but you forgot to add it in your controller too: `public function store(Request $request, $post_id)` and also `$post = Post::find($post_id);`

Comment: Do you have the file / line number from where this error come from? Could also be in `Comment` class when you use `$comments->post()`

Answer (score 0):

Write this code top of the controller....

```
    use App\Post;
```

or

Change this code...

```
    $post = Post::find('id');
```

To

```
    $post = \App\Post::find('id');
```

I think this is solved.

Answer (score -1):

pay attention about file Post.php

use App\Post;

just A is Capital not all APP

Comment: There's not such `use APP\Post;`